# Convert a normal python code to an MPI code

Tags: python, c, performance, multiprocessing, mpi

I have this code that I would like to edit and run it as an MPI code. The array in the code `mass_array1` is a multi-dimensional array with total 'iterations' `i*j` around 80 million. I mean if I flatten the array into 1 dimensional array, there are 80 million elements.

The code takes almost 2 days to run which is quite annoying as it is only small part of the whole project. Since I can log into a cluster and run the code through 20 or so processors (or even more), can someone help me edit this code to an MPI code?

Even writing the MPI code in C language works.

```
#Alotting Black Holes at z=6
from tqdm import tqdm
bhs=[0]*1000

for i in tqdm(range(0,1000),leave=True):
    bhs[i]=np.zeros(len(mass_array1[i]))
    for j in range (len(mass_array1[i])):
        bhs[i][j]=np.random.lognormal(np.log(Mbhthfit6(mass_array1[i],6)[j]),np.log(5))
```

**Current C program using MPI on that cluster:**

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
float epsran;
FILE *fp;
char str[256];
fp=fopen("parameterfile.dat","w");
fprintf(fp,
   " cosmological parameter\n"
       "h:%f\n"
   "omegam:%f\n"
   "omegab:%f\n"
   "omegal:%f\n"
   "sigma8:%f\n"
   "rho0mMpc:%e\n"
   "alpha:%f\n"
   "deltac:%f\n",ndh,
   omegam,omegab,omegal,sigma8,rho0mMpc,alpha,deltac);
fclose(fp);
/* MPI test */
int i,Petot,MyRank;
clock_t start,end;
start = clock();
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Petot);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyRank);
srand((unsigned)(time(NULL)+MyRank));
//printf ("Hello World %d\n%d", MyRank,Petot);
float samples[100];
for(i=0;i<100/Petot;i++){
  samples[i]=halo_samples(1.68,1000);
    outputS(235,30,varipsapp(samples[i],0),MyRank*(100/Petot)+i);
}
printf("Length:%d",(int)(sizeof(samples)/sizeof(samples[0])));
/*    FILE *fpw;
fpw = fopen("Minitial.dat","w");
for(i=0;i<MyRank*(100/Petot);i++){
  fprintf(fpw,"%f\n",samples[i]);
  }
  fclose(fpw);*/
MPI_Finalize();
end = clock();
  }
```

**Submitting a job**

After this, there is a job.sh file that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh     
#$ -S /bin/sh                                                                  
#$ -cwd                                          
#$ -V
#$ -N mergertree
#$ -q all.q@messier04
#$ -q all.q@messier05
#$ -pe openmpi10 20 
#$ -o resultfile/out.txt
#$ -e resultfile/error.txt
                                                       
mpirun -np $NSLOTS ./a.out
```

**Mbhfit6**

This is how I have define Mbhfit6 in my code:

```
def Mbhthfit6(Mdm,z):
    a= 5.00041824
    b= 0.31992748
    Mbhth=(10**a)*(Mdm**b)
    return Mbhth
```

**mass_array1**

Here, I have uploaded one of the files (in zip format) that contains the data for mass_array1.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C-G28OSND7jxqkFZQS3dlW6_40yBN6Fy/view?usp=sharing

*You need to unzip the file into a folder and then use the code below to import it in Python*

This is my code to import the file: (its only 3 MB)

```
#import all the files from directory
dirlist=["bh2e8"]
import time

mass_array1=[0]*1000
#print(mass_array)
#read all the files 
for i,X in enumerate(dirlist):
    exec('filelist=glob.glob("%s/test*.dat")'%(X))
    #exec("mass_array%s=[]"%X)
    initial_mass=[]
    for j,Y in tqdm(enumerate(filelist),position=0, leave=True, total=1000):
        Y=Y.replace(os.sep, '/')
        #Z=int(Y[10:13])
        Z=int(re.findall("\d+", Y)[2])
        #print(Z)
        mass_array1[Z]=[]
        #print('i=',Z,end="\r")
        #print('i=',Z,end="\r")
        exec("initial_partial=np.loadtxt('%s',max_rows=1)"%(Y))
        exec("initial_mass=np.append(initial_mass,initial_partial)")
        exec("mass_partial=np.loadtxt('%s',skiprows=1)"%(Y))
        mass_array1[Z]=np.append(mass_partial,mass_array1[Z])
        #mass_array1[Z]=mass_partial
```

Comment: Why do you create variables with `exec`  instead of using one array?

Comment: _Whenever_ I see repeated variables (e.g. `mass_array0, mass_array1, mass_array2, ..., mass_array999`, then I think there should be _one_ `mass_array` with 1000 elements to replace those individual variables. Usually, I'll see six or so such variables and I'll say "what would you do with 1000 variables"? But, in your case, maybe I should say "what would you do with 1,000,000 variables"? In your code I think you can replace the (e.g.) `mass_array%s,i` with `mass_array[i]` You're [probably] going to _have_ to do this to have any [sane] hope of using MPI

Comment: @KamilCuk that was because I had to run the 'for-loop' on the string variables: mass_array0 to mass_array999. I didn't know any other way to do that without using exec,%s,i

Comment: @CraigEstey Ah! ya that is a little annoying even for me haha. You mean that I should make a list of an array instead of 1000 arrays with different names? Hmm. that might help haha. Thanks

Comment: `'for-loop' on the string variables` so run it on an array, that's what arrays are for.

Comment: Depending on how that cluster is managed in terms of job scheduling, you may not even need MPI. It seems like your data can simply be split up into chunks. Modify your script to process one chunk at a time, then create a runner/master script that splits up the input, calls the subscript on the chunks and accumulates their results. You could do that in C but Python might be easier. Also look into the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Comment: @JanWilamowski Thanks a lot for the response. I looked into python's multiprocessing module and it seems like it might work. But, since I do not have any background in computer science, Its difficult for me to grasp this stuff. I am not sure about how job scheduling works on the cluster and thus I have added an 'MPI code' and 'job-submission' code that I am using right now. Hopefully you can help me with it? Thanks again..

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MPI but if that's the recommended way to schedule jobs on your cluster, you should go with it. Perhaps the cluster admins have additional information on running jobs. Depending on how much you know C vs Python, you could also use [MPI for Python](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

Comment: my first step for getting speed out of python is generally vectorization then numba then multiprocessing, but that would depend on what `Mbhthfit6` looks like. is it possible to share that as well as an example of what `mass_array1` looks like (dimensions, dtype, relative values).

Comment: If `Mbhthfit6` is deterministic (no randomness), It seems you could significantly speed up by calling it only `i` times, and re-using the resulting array inside the inner loop.

Comment: @Aaron much thanks for your comment. I have updated the code: added what Mbhthfit6 is (its just a linear function in log-log), added one of the examples of mass_array1 (files + code to import).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't view this as a big enough set of data to require mpi provided you take an efficient approach to processing the data.

As I mentioned in the comments, I find the best approach to processing large amounts of numerical data is first to use numpy vectorization, then try using numba jit compiling, then use multi-core processing as a last resort. In general that's following the order of easiest to hardest, and will also get you the most speed for the least work. In your case I think vectorization is truly the way to go, and while I was at it, I did some re-organization which isn't really necessary, but helped me to keep track of the data.

```py
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import re

dirlist=[r"C:\Users\aaron\Downloads\bh2e8"]
dirlist = [Path(d) for d in dirlist] #convert directory paths to pathlib.Path objects for ease of file system manipulation

initial_mass = {} #use a dictionary so we don't have to preallocate indices
mass_array = {} #use a dictionary so we don't have to preallocate indices

for dir_path in dirlist:
    for child in dir_path.iterdir():
        m = re.match(".*?test(?P<index>\d+)\.dat$", str(child))
        if m: #if we match the end of the child path as a testxxx.dat file (not another directory or some other file type)
            file_index = int(m["index"])
            with child.open() as f:
                arr = [float(line) for line in f if line.strip()] #1d array of float numbers skipping any empty lines
            initial_mass[file_index] = arr[0]
            mass_array[file_index] = np.array(arr[1:])
```

I started off reading in the data in a slightly different way because I found it more natural to create a dictionary of arrays so the order they were created wouldn't matter. The index of the file (number at the end of the file name) is used as the key of the dictionary, so it is easy to convert it back to a list if you want with something like: `mass_array = list(mass_array[i] for i in range(1000))`

Then looking at the rest of your code, all the numpy functions you used are able to process an entire array of data at a time much faster than one at a time using your inner loop (`j`), so I simply removed the inner loop, and re-wrote the body to use vectorization:

```py
#Alotting Black Holes at z=6

bhs={} #use a dictionary to avoid the need for preallocation

for i, arr in mass_array.items(): #items in python3 iteritems in python2
    
    #inline Mbhthfit6 function, and calculate using vectorization (compute an entire array at once per iteration of `i`)
    bhs[i] = np.random.lognormal(
                                np.log((10**5.00041824)*(arr**0.31992748)),
                                np.log(5)
                                )
```

again if you want to convert the `bhs` dictionary back to a list like you previously had, it's quite simple: `bhs = list(bhs[i] for i in range(1000))`

With these changes (and a relatively powerful PC) the code executed on the data files you provided in under half a second. with just over 700,000 values in the example dataset, if we extrapolate out to 80 million, that should be on the order of a minute or two.

P.S. if you find yourself using `exec` a lot with generated strings of code, you'll almost always find there's a better way to accomplish the same thing usually with just a slightly different data structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It made it quite a lot faster. from 2 days to few minutes. The bounty is yours :D